# How make first automatic numbering cell for a style number 1 not 0?

Tags: stylesheet, cells

I have a cell style "Figure" for a notebook, defined as:

```
Cell[StyleData["Figure", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Text"]],
     MenuSortingValue->10000]
```

In a cell having that cell style, I use menu item Insert > Automatic Numbering... and for the Counter select style Figure; I "Use the counter value corresponding to the location of" "This counter object".

But the number inserted for the first such cell is 0, not 1. So is the second such!

How do I get the first one to be numbered 1 and the subsequent ones numbered 2, 3, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you add `CounterIncrements`

Cell[StyleData["Figure",StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Text"]],
 CounterIncrements->"Figure",
 MenuSortingValue->10000]

[image]

[image]

then it works fine

[image]